# Is it advisable to send news letter from own servers or using mail clients like conatantContact & MailChimp

Tags: email, email-spam, newsletter

Is it advisable to send news letter from own servers or using mail clients like conatantContact & MailChimp.

my webserver has lot of limitation in sending newsletter(double opt-in) especially the email count as this is a shared servers.

Please suggest and also some cheap and best Mail clients like conatantContact & MailChimp.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Gourav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely advise you to outsource your newsletter-related activities to a third party provider such as [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/), [MadMimi](http://www.madmimi.com/), or [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/). Why?

1. Resources - you are going to use their resources rather than your own, which frees up your server from having to handle that load
2. Deliverability - they are taking care of the headache of having to send out all of those emails and making sure they get to their intended recipient
3. Design - they have easy to use templates that will make your newsletter look and read much better
4. CAN-SPAM Compliance - goes hand in hand with deliverability, but at least you won't have to worry about list management, right?

At the end of the day, it's your call, but why bother setting up your own solution when they can do it for probably much cheaper?

Hope that helps.

Comment: As someone who was maintaining a 10-year-old home-grown system and migrated to Contactology, this is the right answer. One thing left out is IP blacklisting -- it is real and dealing with DKIM signing and feedback loops is something best left to third parties. If you're sending bulk e-mail -- even if it's "legit" -- it's best not to DIY.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I would say this falls under "Deliverability," but you make a valid point as Deliverability is a HUGE umbrella that involves a lot of different things.